# Finding the time difference between events in csv file using datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, datetime, time

I have a long list of weather variables. The rows come in couples, with the first row representing the start time of the event, while the second row represents the end time of the event. The data file is csv. An example of the data is below, with 6 six rows, representing 3 couples (and therefore 3 events). There are thousands of rows of data, so it is possible there are a few exceptions (dates that aren't paired to another date).

```
hd,Station Number,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Local time,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Local standard time,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Universal coordinated time,Precipitation since last (AWS) observation in mm,Quality of precipitation since last (AWS) observation value,Air Temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature,Air temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature (1-minute maximum),Air temperature (1-minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature (1-minute minimum),Wet bulb temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of Wet bulb temperature,Wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum),Wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum),Dew point temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of dew point temperature,Dew point temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of Dew point Temperature (1-minute maximum),Dew point temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of Dew point Temperature (1 minute minimum),Relative humidity in percentage %,Quality of relative humidity,Relative humidity (1 minute maximum) in percentage %,Quality of relative humidity (1 minute maximum),Relative humidity (1 minute minimum) in percentage %,Quality of Relative humidity (1 minute minimum),Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h,Wind (1 minute) speed quality,Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) in km/h,Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) quality,Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true,Wind (1 minute) direction quality,Standard deviation of wind (1 minute),Standard deviation of wind (1 minute) direction quality,Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) in km/h,Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) quality,Visibility (automatic - one minute data) in km,Quality of visibility (automatic - one minute data),Mean sea level pressure in hPa,Quality of mean sea level pressure,Station level pressure in hPa,Quality of station level pressure,QNH pressure in hPa,Quality of QNH pressure,#
hd,40842,2000,3,21,12,32,2000,3,21,12,32,2000,3,21,12,32,0,N,21,N,21,N,21,N,20.4,N,20.4,N,20.4,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,94,N,,N,,N,0,N,0,N,91,N,22,N,0,N,,N,1016.5,N,1015.4,N,1016.5,N,#
hd,40842,2000,3,21,12,50,2000,3,21,12,50,2000,3,21,12,50,0.2,N,20.9,N,20.9,N,20.9,N,20.4,N,20.5,N,20.4,N,20.2,N,20.3,N,20.2,N,95,N,,N,,N,0,N,0,N,42,N,2,N,0,N,,N,1016.6,N,1015.5,N,1016.6,N,#
hd,40842,2000,3,22,13,39,2000,3,22,13,39,2000,3,22,13,39,0,N,20.4,N,20.4,N,20.4,N,20.2,N,20.2,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,19.9,N,98,N,,N,,N,8,N,5,N,10,N,9,N,11,N,,N,1013.3,N,1012.2,N,1013.3,N,#
hd,40842,2000,3,22,13,47,2000,3,22,13,47,2000,3,22,13,47,0,N,20.5,N,20.5,N,20.5,N,20.2,N,20.2,N,20.2,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,20,N,97,N,,N,,N,4,N,0,N,56,N,75,N,5,N,,N,1013.2,N,1012.1,N,1013.2,N,#
hd,40842,2000,3,23,11,0,2000,3,23,11,0,2000,3,23,11,0,0,N,23.4,N,23.4,N,23.3,N,21.3,N,21.4,N,21.3,N,20.2,N,20.3,N,20.2,N,82,N,,N,,N,8,N,5,N,66,N,2,N,9,N,,N,1013.6,N,1012.5,N,1013.6,N,#
hd,40842,2000,3,23,13,27,2000,3,23,13,27,2000,3,23,13,27,0,N,23.3,N,23.3,N,23.3,N,21.6,N,21.6,N,21.5,N,20.7,N,20.7,N,20.6,N,85,N,,N,,N,5,N,4,N,108,N,5,N,5,N,,N,1013.5,N,1012.4,N,1013.5,N,#
```

For my analysis, I only want to consider events that are at least two hours in duration. Fore example, in the data above, only the final couple of rows would be written to the new csv file (in the same format). Is there an easy way to do this? So far I've made the bare bones of the code that might be able to do this, but I'm unsure how to implement datetime in this example. The part I am unsure about follows the hashtag.

```
import csv
import datetime

with open("X:\weatherresults\sea_breeze_dates_2000_2011.csv", "rb") as input, open("X:\weatherresults\sea_breeze_dates_2000_2011_time_filtered.csv", "wb") as wanted:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    writer_wanted = csv.DictWriter(wanted, fieldnames, delimiter=",")
    prev_row = None
    for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):
        try:
            dt = datetime.date(year=int(row["Year Month Day Hour Minutes in YYYY"]), month=int(row["MM"]), day=int(row["DD"])), hour=int(row["HH24"])
            dta = prev_row['dt']            
            if prev_row is not None and dt > prev_row['dt'] and # (dt-dta) => 2hours:
                writer_wanted.writerow(prev_row['row'])
                writer_wanted.writerow(row)
            prev_row = {'row':row, 'dt':dt}
        except:
            print "Failed to parse line", line_number
            print row
```

The if clause in the try command is the part that is stumping me. How do I express that the difference between the start and end of the event must be at least two hours in order for that row couple to written to the new csv file?

Comment: I don't see how prev_row ever is set...The first time through you're going to throw on 'dta = prev_row[...]' and any subsequent iteration you'll throw on the same line

Comment: As for checking > 2hrs, use https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.  .total_seconds()

Comment: @Stanton You can actually directly compare `timedelta` objects.

Comment: Your current code doesn't consider the lines as "couples". It compares 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc... BTW, how do you know when a line is an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta` to represent the minimum two hour time delta. Since you want to compare event begin and end times, you can read two lines at a time and skip tracking the previous line.

```
import csv
import datetime

minimum_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

input_fn = r"X:\weatherresults\sea_breeze_dates_2000_2011.csv"
wanted_fn = r"X:\weatherresults\sea_breeze_dates_2000_2011_time_filtered.csv"

with open(input_fn, "rb") as input, open(wanted_fn, "wb") as wanted:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    writer_wanted = csv.DictWriter(wanted, fieldnames, delimiter=",")
    try:
        while 1:
            try:
                begin = next(reader)
                begin_dt = datetime.datetime(
                    year=int(begin["Year Month Day Hour Minutes in YYYY"]),
                    month=int(begin["MM"]), day=int(begin["DD"]), 
                    hour=int(begin["HH24"]))
                end = next(reader)
                end_dt = datetime.datetime(
                    year=int(end["Year Month Day Hour Minutes in YYYY"]),
                    month=int(end["MM"]), day=int(end["DD"]), 
                    hour=int(end["HH24"]))
                if end_dt - begin_dt > minimum_delta:
                    writer_wanted.writerow(begin)
                    writer_wanted.writerow(end)
            except ValueError as e:
                print "Failed to parse line", line_number
                print row
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Will reading two lines at a time result in an error when it stumbles across one of the lines in there that is not paired with another row? there may be a few in there, there are thousands of lines, my previous parsing may have produced a few rows that aren't linked.

Comment: Yes, this will break for unpaired lines. The question is... how do you know when a line is unpaired?

Comment: Hi Tdelaney, I've attempted to implement your code. Originally, it did not work, the output file seemed to be identical to the input file. However I realised that the very first row was not paired. Upon deleting it the program ran perfectly. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: the only addition comment is that for a minimum of 2 hours the code should be minimum_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1) instead of minimum_delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

Comment: @JossKirk No, it should be 2 hours. Suppose you compare 10:01 AM - 9:00 AM. That's 1 hour 1 minute which is greater than 1 hour but less that 2 hours.

Comment: yes but if end_dt - begin_dt > minimum_delta and we are using a value of minimum_delta of 2, this will exclude results of 2?

Comment: @JossKirk `timedelta` has a resolution in microseconds - if you initialize the hour, it just assumes minutes, seconds, etc... of 0 but keeps the microsecond resolution. So, we have the edge case of exactly 2 hours verses 2 hours plus 1 microsecond. I interpreted the question as everything over 2 hours but if you want to include 2 hours exactly, just do `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

[`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) is the module used for comparing time spans:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> old_time = datetime.datetime.now() #Then wait a little while before running the next line
>>> new_time = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> (new_time - old_time).total_seconds()
4.302
>>> (new_time - old_time) < datetime.timedelta(seconds=2)
False
>>> (new_time - old_time) < datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a typo in your code for the year part of the date. 
Correct CSV field is as below. You had just 'Hour' instead of 'Hours'

> Year Month Day Hour**s** Minutes in YYYY

Below code works for me

```
import sys
import csv
import datetime

with open("/tmp/csvinput", "rb") as input, open("/tmp/csv.out","wb") as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input,delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    writer_wanted = csv.DictWriter(output, reader.fieldnames, delimiter=",")
    prev_row = None
    for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):
        try:
            cur_dt = datetime.datetime(year=int(row['Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY']), month=int(row['MM']), day=int(row['DD']), hour=int(row['HH24']))
            print line_number,cur_dt
            if not prev_row:
                prev_row = {'row': row, 'dt': cur_dt}
                continue
            prev_dt = prev_row['dt']
            if (cur_dt - prev_dt) >= datetime.timedelta(hours=2) :
                writer_wanted.writerow(prev_row['row'])
                writer_wanted.writerow(row)
            else:
                prev_row = None
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print "Failed with exception",e
```